# Where does GNOME 3 store schema/setting overrides?

Tags: gnome3, fedora-24

Related to [another question](https://ask.puppet.com/question/27731/how-to-apply-gnome-settings-to-current-session/), which directory (if any) does GNOME 3.20 on Fedora 24 monitor for schema/setting overrides? According to many sources I should be able to put overrides in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/*.gschema.override`, but I can't get them to work (even after running `sudo /usr/bin/glib-compile-schemas --strict /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas`). Are schema overrides still supported?

Possibly related to this: After manually creating a custom keyboard shortcut I can't find where this is stored. I tried `grep`ping `~/.*`, `/etc` and `/usr/share`, and the only match was in a binary file `~/.config/dconf/user`.

Comment: _Schema_ overrides or _setting_ overrides? The schemas only describe acceptable values, not actual ones...

Comment: @grawity The file names are `*.gschema.override`, but anything is possible I suppose. GNOME is too complicated for me.

Comment: Well, that particular format is still mentioned in glib-compile-schemas manpage, so I'd assume it's still supported?

Comment: After trying for half a day to make it work I'm not taking anything for granted. And since `glib-compile-schemas` isn't complaining I have no idea why the settings are not applied.

Comment: Because schema overrides only override the _schemas_ (that is, default values) but have nothing to do with enforcing specific settings, would be my guess.

Comment: @grawity [puppet-gnome](https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-gnome) specifically creates such files to change settings, so I'm pretty sure that's not the case.